# Why does scaling a tikz picture cause everything within the scope of transform canvas to disappear?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, transformation

I drew a tikz picture, but after scaling the picture using `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=200/(\hsize-24)]`, everything inside the scope of transform canvas disappear. could someone explain this?

This the original tikz picture

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide, pgfmath, pstricks}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.markings, angles,
quotes, calc, arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}
%
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,51,255}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,153,0}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{174,214,241}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{161,207,223}
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{255,220,0}
\colorlet{dcolor}{blue}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\preserve}{1/\mya}
\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[scale=1.2]} , thick,rotate=0 ] 

%
\newcommand\height{10}
%
\newcommand\Ac{-4}
%
\newcommand\Bc{27.46586300953384}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{\Bc+\Ac}
\draw (0,-0.2) node [color=black,fill=white,below] {$Q$};
\draw [fill=black] (\Ac-0.1*\distance,0)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,0)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,0.01*\height)--(\Ac-0.1*\distance,0.01*\height)--cycle;
\draw [fill=black] (\Ac-0.1*\distance,\height)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,\height)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,1.01*\height)--(\Ac-0.1*\distance,1.01*\height)--cycle;
\draw [black,densely dashed](0,0)--(0,\height);


%
\coordinate (pulleyCenter) at (0,0.9*\height);
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pulleyRadius}{0.0375*\height}

\draw (0,0.9*\height-\pulleyRadius) node [color=black,fill=white,below] {$P$};

\draw [line width = 0.2*\distance,line cap=round](0,0.9*\height)--(0,0.995*\height);
\draw [line width = 0.2*\distance]([shift={(0,\height)}]0:-0.025*\height) arc[radius=0.025*\height, start angle=180, end angle= 360];

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{\Bc-0.04*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bx}{\Bc+0.04*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lowerwidth}{\bx-\ax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aby}{0.2+0.01*\height}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\Bc-0.08*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cx}{\Bc+0.08*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\upperwidth}{\cx-\dx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cartheight}{1.25*\lowerwidth}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dcy}{\aby+\cartheight}
\coordinate(a) at (\ax,\aby);
\coordinate(b) at (\bx,\aby);
\coordinate(d) at (\dx,\dcy);
\coordinate(c) at (\cx,\dcy);


\pgfmathsetmacro{\adx}{\Bc-0.06*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ady}{\aby+0.5*\cartheight}
\coordinate (c1) at (\adx,\ady);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c1)--++(180:0.01*\Bc) coordinate (e1);


\coordinate (c2) at (\Bc+0.06*\distance,\ady);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c2)--++(0:0.01*\Bc) coordinate (e2);


\draw [line width = 0.005*\height cm,blue!200,fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--cycle;

\tkzTangent[from with R=e1](pulleyCenter,\pulleyRadius cm) \tkzGetPoints{D1}{D2}

\draw[yellow, line width = 0.010*\height cm,line cap =round](e1)--(D1);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c1)--(e1);
\draw [line width = 0.005*\height cm,blue!200,fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--cycle;

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelax}{0.25*\lowerwidth+\ax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelbx}{0.75*\lowerwidth+\ax}
\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelax,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelax,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);

\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);

\draw (\Bc,\ady) node [color=black] {$A$};


\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{\Ac-\Bc}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=\shift cm}]
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c1)--(e1);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c2)--(e2);
\coordinate (pulleyCenter) at (-1*\shift,0.9*\height);
\tkzTangent[from with R=e2](pulleyCenter,\pulleyRadius cm) \tkzGetPoints{D1}{D2}
\draw[yellow, line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap =round](e2)--(D2);
\draw[gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c2)--(e2);
\draw [line width = 0.005*\height cm,blue!200,fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--cycle;
\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelax,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelax,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);

\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);
\draw (\Bc,\ady) node [color=black] {$B$};

\draw [gray,fill=gray!50,line width = 0.005*\height cm](pulleyCenter) circle(\pulleyRadius);
\end{scope}



\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, this is the same tikz picture after using `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=200/(\hsize-24)]`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide, pgfmath, pstricks}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.markings, angles,
quotes, calc, arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}
%
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,51,255}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,153,0}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{174,214,241}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{161,207,223}
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{255,220,0}
\colorlet{dcolor}{blue}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=200/(\hsize-24)]

\pgfgettransformentries{\mya}{\myb}{\myc}{\myd}{\mys}{\myt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\preserve}{1/\mya}
\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[scale=1.2]} , thick,rotate=0 ] 

%
\newcommand\height{10}
%
\newcommand\Ac{-4}
%
\newcommand\Bc{27.46586300953384}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{\Bc+\Ac}
\draw (0,-0.2) node [color=black,fill=white,below] {$Q$};
\draw [fill=black] (\Ac-0.1*\distance,0)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,0)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,0.01*\height)--(\Ac-0.1*\distance,0.01*\height)--cycle;
\draw [fill=black] (\Ac-0.1*\distance,\height)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,\height)--(\Bc+0.1*\distance,1.01*\height)--(\Ac-0.1*\distance,1.01*\height)--cycle;
\draw [black,densely dashed](0,0)--(0,\height);


%
\coordinate (pulleyCenter) at (0,0.9*\height);
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pulleyRadius}{0.0375*\height}

\draw (0,0.9*\height-\pulleyRadius) node [color=black,fill=white,below] {$P$};

\draw [line width = 0.2*\distance,line cap=round](0,0.9*\height)--(0,0.995*\height);
\draw [line width = 0.2*\distance]([shift={(0,\height)}]0:-0.025*\height) arc[radius=0.025*\height, start angle=180, end angle= 360];

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{\Bc-0.04*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bx}{\Bc+0.04*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lowerwidth}{\bx-\ax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aby}{0.2+0.01*\height}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\Bc-0.08*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cx}{\Bc+0.08*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\upperwidth}{\cx-\dx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cartheight}{1.25*\lowerwidth}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dcy}{\aby+\cartheight}
\coordinate(a) at (\ax,\aby);
\coordinate(b) at (\bx,\aby);
\coordinate(d) at (\dx,\dcy);
\coordinate(c) at (\cx,\dcy);


\pgfmathsetmacro{\adx}{\Bc-0.06*\distance}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ady}{\aby+0.5*\cartheight}
\coordinate (c1) at (\adx,\ady);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c1)--++(180:0.01*\Bc) coordinate (e1);


\coordinate (c2) at (\Bc+0.06*\distance,\ady);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c2)--++(0:0.01*\Bc) coordinate (e2);


\draw [line width = 0.005*\height cm,blue!200,fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--cycle;

\tkzTangent[from with R=e1](pulleyCenter,\pulleyRadius cm) \tkzGetPoints{D1}{D2}

\draw[yellow, line width = 0.010*\height cm,line cap =round](e1)--(D1);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c1)--(e1);
\draw [line width = 0.005*\height cm,blue!200,fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--cycle;

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelax}{0.25*\lowerwidth+\ax}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelbx}{0.75*\lowerwidth+\ax}
\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelax,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelax,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);

\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);

\draw (\Bc,\ady) node [color=black] {$A$};


\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{\Ac-\Bc}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=\shift cm}]
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c1)--(e1);
\draw [gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c2)--(e2);
\coordinate (pulleyCenter) at (-1*\shift,0.9*\height);
\tkzTangent[from with R=e2](pulleyCenter,\pulleyRadius cm) \tkzGetPoints{D1}{D2}
\draw[yellow, line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap =round](e2)--(D2);
\draw[gray!120,line width = 0.01*\height cm,line cap=round](c2)--(e2);
\draw [line width = 0.005*\height cm,blue!200,fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--cycle;
\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelax,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelax,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);

\draw[black,fill=black](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(\aby-0.011*\height);
\draw[black,fill=gray](\wheelbx,\aby)circle(0.75*\aby-0.75*0.011*\height);
\draw (\Bc,\ady) node [color=black] {$B$};

\draw [gray,fill=gray!50,line width = 0.005*\height cm](pulleyCenter) circle(\pulleyRadius);
\end{scope}



\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try only with `\begin{scope}[xshift=\shift cm]`? Any reason for the low level transform?

Comment: I tried but it caused the coordinates defined outside the transform canvase scope, to stay the same. I tried tweaking the \shift value manually in the scaled version to see what's going on and it turned out that when I used `transform canvas={xshift=\shift-18.5 cm}`. it looked fine, so it's probably because the scaling applies differently to xshift in the transform canvas. but I need to find the exact relation between the scaling factor and xshift so that I can make this work for different values.

Comment: I think I've found the problem, the scaling doesn't apply to `\shift` in `transform canvas={xshift=\shift cm}`
so I have to do it manually, then used the scaled shift (`\shifta`) in the the transform, but use the normal shift anywhere else
`\pgfmathsetmacro{\shifta}{(\Ac-\Bc)*\mya}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{\Ac-\Bc}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=\shifta cm}]`
where `\mya` is the vertical scale

Comment: @CarLateX I will, I just decided to wait for a few days in case someone had a better suggestion.

Comment: @K.Ali OK, let's wait for a better answer, then!

Comment: @CarLaTex, I am not sure what's your problem, but it's the etiquette to wait for other people to answer and comment to improve, otherwise it seems that you are just trying to generate reputation. I am writing the answer now anyway.

Comment: @K.Ali No problem. Probably I badly explain myself. I was saying that you can do as you like!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @K.Ali Don't worry, :):):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling of the tikz picture doesn't apply to the xshift inside the transform canvas, so all I had to do was apply the scaling to the shift outside the transform canvas, and then use the scaled value inside the canvas transform.
so I used this

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{\Ac-\Bc}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shifta}{200/(\hsize-24)*\shift}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=\shifta cm}]
```

instead of this

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{\Ac-\Bc}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=\shift cm}]
```

and the rest of the code is just the same.