# Mutiple mindmaps, how to scope and move/position properly sub mindmaps?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I'd like to create a poster with multiple Mindmaps. Each mindmap would be a lecture of the course, so 8 independent mindmaps i'd like eventually to position in a poster like the one below.

[image: MinmapPoster]

I am not satisfied with the organization I had so far and thanks to @Schrodingers cat [Mindmap, growcyclic from?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532504/mindmap-growcyclic-from) I managed to have more flexibility to rotate more circular and harmonious mindmaps.
[image]

I put every single Mindmap in a scope. However as you can see in my simplified MWE below, the scope is not shifting the mindmap as a block (keeping its circular disposition in the block) but shifting the central node only.

My question seems related to [Why does scaling a tikz picture cause everything within the scope of transform canvas to disappear?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365234/why-does-scaling-a-tikz-picture-cause-everything-within-the-scope-of-transform-c)
 but from then :/

[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,decorations}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcount\tikzcountgrandchild
\def\tikz@grow@concentric{%
  \pgftransformreset% 
  \pgftransformrotate{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/overall rotation}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(\tikzcountgrandchild)}%
  \ifnum\tikztreelevel=1
    \pgftransformrotate{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/noc}-1)/2}%
  \fi
  \pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
  \ifnum\tikztreelevel=2
    \global\advance\tikzcountgrandchild by1
 \fi
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{overall rotation/.initial=0,
    noc/.initial=0,
    branch color/.style={
        concept color=#1!white,
        every child/.append style={concept color=#1!white!30!white},
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[text width=1.5cm,align=flush center,
            mindmap,growth function=\tikz@grow@concentric,
            overall rotation=-45,
            sibling angle=360/30,
            nodes={concept},
            concept color=green!70!black,
            root concept/.append style={ ball color=green!50, line width=1.5ex,text=green!40!black,font=\huge\bfseries\scshape,minimum size=4.5cm,text width=4.5cm,},                   
            level 1/.style={,level distance=8cm,font=\Large,minimum size=3.0cm,text width=2.5cm,},
            level 2/.style={level distance=12cm,font=\large,minimum size=2.0cm,text width=2.0cm}
        ]
        \node [root concept]{Clients} 
        child[noc=3,branch color=green!70]{node {Retail} 
            child[] {node {CGPI}} 
            child[] {node {Banques priv\'ees}} 
            child[] {node {Retail banking}} 
        }
        child[noc=3,branch color=green!70]{node {ALM} 
            child[] {node {Mutuelles}} 
            child[] {node {Assurances}} 
            child[] {node {Caisse de retraite}}         
        } 
        child[noc=1,branch color=green!80]{node {Directions financi\'eres} 
            child[] {node {Corporate}} 
        } 
        child[noc=3,branch color=green!70]{node {Instrument specialists} 
            child {node {Asset Managers traditionnels}} 
            child {node {Hedge funds}} 
            child {node {Trading desks form other banks}} 
        } 
        ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm,text width=1.5cm,align=flush center,
            mindmap,growth function=\tikz@grow@concentric,
            overall rotation=45,
            sibling angle=360/30,
            nodes={concept},
            concept color=yellow!70!black,
            root concept/.append style={ ball color=yellow!50, line width=1.5ex,text=yellow!40!black,font=\huge\bfseries\scshape,minimum size=4.5cm,text width=4.5cm,},                   
            level 1/.style={,level distance=8cm,font=\Large,minimum size=3.0cm,text width=2.5cm,},
            level 2/.style={level distance=12cm,font=\large,minimum size=2.0cm,text width=2.0cm}
        ]
        \node [root concept]{Suppliers} 
        child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!70]{node {Retail} 
            child[] {node {CGPI}} 
            child[] {node {Banques priv\'ees}} 
            child[] {node {Retail banking}} 
        }
        child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!70]{node {ALM} 
            child[] {node {Mutuelles}} 
            child[] {node {Assurances}} 
            child[] {node {Caisse de retraite}}         
        } 
        child[noc=1,branch color=yellow!80]{node {Directions financi\'eres} 
            child[] {node {Corporate}} 
        } 
        child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!70]{node {Instrument specialists} 
            child {node {Asset Managers traditionnels}} 
            child {node {Hedge funds}} 
            child {node {Trading desks form other banks}} 
        } 
        ;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The Cat solution already helped me to produce this improvable solution
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be done all in the same document...? Otherwise I wonder if each one could be created separately, and then the poster might be build by layering the individual images...? Not sure if that would be helpful or not....

Comment: @cmhughes My original solution consisted of creating each mindmap and position each resulting pdf on a poster but I lose all possibility to connect nodes after :/ Am investigating the "transform canvas" option but no result so far... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts/26852#26852

Comment: @cmhughes after multiple attempts, with 8 mindmaps to display, the code becomes too messy and it turns your idea is very good. May I ask you how you would proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As before, the problem comes from `\pgftransfromreset`. As a first proposal, I added two keys, `overall xshift` and `overall yshift` to fix this. They can be combined with ordinary shifts using `Xshift` and `Yshift`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,decorations}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcount\tikzcountgrandchild
\def\tikz@grow@concentric{%
  \pgftransformreset%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/overall xshift}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/overall yshift}}}% 
  \pgftransformrotate{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/overall rotation}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(\tikzcountgrandchild)}%
  \ifnum\tikztreelevel=1
    \pgftransformrotate{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/noc}-1)/2}%
  \fi
  \pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
  \ifnum\tikztreelevel=2
    \global\advance\tikzcountgrandchild by1
 \fi
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{overall rotation/.initial=0,
    overall xshift/.initial=0pt,
    overall yshift/.initial=0pt,
    Xshift/.style={xshift=#1,overall xshift=#1},
    Yshift/.style={yshift=#1,overall yshift=#1},
    noc/.initial=0,
    branch color/.style={
        concept color=#1!white,
        every child/.append style={concept color=#1!white!30!white},
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[text width=1.5cm,align=flush center,
            mindmap,growth function=\tikz@grow@concentric,
            overall rotation=-45,
            sibling angle=360/30,
            nodes={concept},
            concept color=green!70!black,
            root concept/.append style={ ball color=green!50, line width=1.5ex,text=green!40!black,font=\huge\bfseries\scshape,minimum size=4.5cm,text width=4.5cm,},                   
            level 1/.style={,level distance=8cm,font=\Large,minimum size=3.0cm,text width=2.5cm,},
            level 2/.style={level distance=12cm,font=\large,minimum size=2.0cm,text width=2.0cm}
        ]
        \node [root concept]{Clients} 
        child[noc=3,branch color=green!70]{node {Retail} 
            child[] {node {CGPI}} 
            child[] {node {Banques priv\'ees}} 
            child[] {node {Retail banking}} 
        }
        child[noc=3,branch color=green!70]{node {ALM} 
            child[] {node {Mutuelles}} 
            child[] {node {Assurances}} 
            child[] {node {Caisse de retraite}}         
        } 
        child[noc=1,branch color=green!80]{node {Directions financi\'eres} 
            child[] {node {Corporate}} 
        } 
        child[noc=3,branch color=green!70]{node {Instrument specialists} 
            child {node {Asset Managers traditionnels}} 
            child {node {Hedge funds}} 
            child {node {Trading desks form other banks}} 
        } 
        ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[Xshift=-5cm,text width=1.5cm,align=flush center,
            mindmap,growth function=\tikz@grow@concentric,
            overall rotation=45,
            sibling angle=360/30,
            nodes={concept},
            concept color=yellow!70!black,
            root concept/.append style={ ball color=yellow!50, line width=1.5ex,text=yellow!40!black,font=\huge\bfseries\scshape,minimum size=4.5cm,text width=4.5cm,},                   
            level 1/.style={,level distance=8cm,font=\Large,minimum size=3.0cm,text width=2.5cm,},
            level 2/.style={level distance=12cm,font=\large,minimum size=2.0cm,text width=2.0cm}
        ]
        \node [root concept]{Suppliers} 
        child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!70]{node {Retail} 
            child[] {node {CGPI}} 
            child[] {node {Banques priv\'ees}} 
            child[] {node {Retail banking}} 
        }
        child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!70]{node {ALM} 
            child[] {node {Mutuelles}} 
            child[] {node {Assurances}} 
            child[] {node {Caisse de retraite}}         
        } 
        child[noc=1,branch color=yellow!80]{node {Directions financi\'eres} 
            child[] {node {Corporate}} 
        } 
        child[noc=3,branch color=yellow!70]{node {Instrument specialists} 
            child {node {Asset Managers traditionnels}} 
            child {node {Hedge funds}} 
            child {node {Trading desks form other banks}} 
        } 
        ;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm ! I'll be able to show you the result soon :) Merci for your help again.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb You're welcome! I plan to see a bit later if one can make it more user friendly.

Comment: I'd be happy to see it ! I posted the result of your help today.